# Conditional Binomial - Does sample space change given previous results?

Tags: r, statistics, cross-validation

I am brushing up on some probability using R - and came across the following question:

It is estimated that approximately 20% of marketing calls result in a sale. What is the probability that the last 4 marketing calls made on a day (where 12 calls are made) are the only ones to result in a sale?

My initial thought would be that the probability of the last 4 calls being a sale is independent - ergo its a binomial distribution and can use dbinom(4,12,.2). However after looking at it further - I'm not sure if the sample space changes to just the remaining 4 calls, ergo dbinom(4,4,.2)

Also my understanding of the Binomial PMF

```
Pz({Z=z})= (n¦z)p^z(1-p)^(n-z)
```

which i believe that R replicates in the dbinom function, would provide the probability of any 4 successes, not specifically the last 4 items.

Is it a simple case of removing the N Choose Z piece of the PMF function? Is there an equivalent function in R?

Havnt looked at probability in a while so appreciate any assistance!

Comment: Hi, that's not exactly a question of R programming, rather a statiscal or probabilistic question .. so you should move it to cross validated ..anyway, what's puzzling you ? If they are indepedant, they are independant .. no ?

Comment: Hi - thanks for the comment - I have updated the question to give a little more clarity on what I am asking

Comment: You just get 4 success among for trail ... so that should be enough. As far as the trial are indepandant, the probability doesn't change if you consider the four last ones, or any four of the twelve in the day ..